# High Contrast and CSS sprites

Tags: css, user-interface, firefox, accessibility, opera

I'm working on a project that it has to be accessible to everyone and I have some problems when the PC is in High Contrast mode.

Here the project demo version (the new version on development is different and we have removed the accessibility theme because are useless if the PC is set to high contrast).

http://www.traffwebdemo.co.uk/consult/

The icons in the legend are made with CSS sprites, so when you are in High Contrast they disappear.

- So far I've solved the problem in IE and Edge with:

-ms-high-contrast-adjust

- In Chrome there is a Plugin called:

High Contrast and it change the color on the website (change the icon and the map colors)

- In Firefox the theme changes the colors and the icons disappear.
- In Opera it seems that the High contrast theme doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem in Firefox?

there is an AddOn for Opera that allows you to add a High Contrast theme (it has to change also the map color or simply don't touch the icon colors, look at chrome plugin)?

I dont't care too much about Opera, What I really need to solve is Firefox.

UPDATE.
This Problem seems to be related just to Windows, I tested the project on my MAC and it works well on every browser.